# How to exit "go run" in the GoSublime's command-shell?

Tags: windows, go, sublimetext3

When i do `go run`, the command-shell doesn't halt and i have to close my web server from the task manager. Is it possible to cancel it from sublime text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yup. press ctrl+b to go to the build console and type `tskill`.

This will prompt a dialog with running processes you can kill.

Comment: BTW I so hate that the runner buffers the output and doesn't let you see it in real time. It makes running long tasks with it useless. I usually just `go install` my stuff and run them from the console.

Comment: That's weird, i get prompted to kill the process using the tskill command, press yes, but the process doesn't get closed.

Comment: Perhaps it's a Windows bug, I'm doing it on Linux and it works. But as I wrote in the comment, `go run` pretty much sucks and I'd avoid it.

Comment: `tskill` does not work on Mac. Searched web and found that page

Comment: I've started using GuSublime-next, which is a fork by the original author that is almost a rewrite from scratch. It solves a lot of problems, like the output buffering. It's not stable yet, but it works, and the author of GoSublime told me he's using it himself exclusively, so it's pretty useful.

Comment: There is an [official Go Sublime plugin](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Golang-nuts/8oCSjAiKXUQ) now so you don't have to.